# 別のjspファイルから変数を呼び出す

Tags: javascript, jsp

以下のjspファイルのjavascript部分の変数dialogを別のjspから呼び出すにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

```
var dialog = Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow(
    {
        dialog: {
            align: {
                node: null,
                points: ['tc', 'tc']
            },
            constrain2view: true,
            cssClass: 'profile-dialog',
            destroyOnClose: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 1060
        },
        cache: false,
        id: '<portlet:namespace />scheduleDialog',
        refreshWindow: window,
        title: '<h4 class="modal-title"><img src="<%= imageFolderPath %>/icon01.png" alt="<liferay-ui:message key="edit-schedule" />" />'
            + template.replace('_PLACE_HOLDER_', dispName)  + '</h4>',
        uri: url
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptはクライアント（ブラウザ上）で動作し、JSPはサーバー（サーブレットコンテナ）上で動作するので、JavaScriptの変数をJSPから参照することはできません。